# What is a good way to get a C++ and WPF app to communicate

Tags: c++, wpf, ipc

I have a C++ dll which is a plug-in to ADOBE Acrobat. It needs to talk often ( to and fro) and with a fair amount of complicated data-structures to a WPF process.
Any thoughts of what might be the best way to go . Need something that is a little long term and maintainable, in other words would love some ideas around something that lets both process make what looks like  methods calls  and some infrastructure piece does the marshaling and dispatch . I've tried Windows messages but ran into some conflict issues on ADOBE, also not really interested in anything that causes the dll to get adobe to load the CLR. Only other things that come to my mind are named pipes or http.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Will memory mapped file work for you?

Comment: COM is perfectly valid solution for this. Unlike pipes/MMFs, you will not need to invent your own protocol

Answer (score 1):

Named pipes could do but you won't get a feeling of just calling functions. Named pipe are quite low-level IPC. Other IPC options are:

- Windows RPC, you definitely get a feeling of just calling functions.
- What about hosting a COM object in WPF application and calling it from the Adobe plugin?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with COM:

- Implement an interface in WPF app
- generate a typelib (e.g by using `regasm`)
- import the typelib into C++ dll
- communicate

if you need bidirectional communication, C++ dll can also implement a COM interface which is then accessed from WPF application.

This is what I have used to connect legacy C++ app with new .NET service, and it works great. The biggest issue is to find people who know COM, but fortunately this doesn't require a deep understanding of COM.

Answer (score 0):

your hint with COM is very intersting. I tried to implement this concept.
I have created an interface in my WPF CallDllFromWpf3Interface project:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CallDllFromWpf3Interface
{
  [Guid("F6E0E2E8-CCC6-487B-8BF1-261265061E6A")]
  public interface SetValueInterface
  {
    void SetValue(int value);
  }
}
```

Then I have generated the typelib with the regasm tool:
regasm CallDllFromWpf3Interface.exe /tlb

With the "oleview" tool I can see the typelib and the interface.

The next step was to create a c++ dll project called "CallSetValueInterface".

In my CallSetValueInterface.cpp file I wrote this lines:

```
#import "D:\Thomas\Programming\WPF\Basics\CallDllFromWpf\CallDllFromWpf3Interface\CallDllFromWpf3Interface\bin\Debug\CallDllFromWpf3Interface.tlb"

void
CallSetValueInterface::startAcq(void)
{
    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    CallDllFromWpf3Interface::SetValueInterfacePtr Svip("f6e0e2e8-ccc6-487b-8bf1-261265061e6a");
    Svip->SetValue(55);
    Svip = NULL;
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

After a successful build of the dll project I copied "CallSetValueInterface.dll" to the "CallDllFromWpf3Interface" project.

Finally I changed my WPF code to:

```
#region SetValueInterface Members

public void SetValue(int value)
{
  MyValue = value;
}

#endregion

[DllImport("CallSetValueInterface.dll", EntryPoint = "startAcq", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern void StartAcqFromDll();

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  StartAcqFromDll();
}
```

And when the debugger came to StartAcqFromDll() there occurred an error dialog "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in CallDllFromWpf3Interface.exe".

Does anybody know whats going wrong?

Regards,

ThomasL.